# Regarding linking external native libs (opencv c++) in gradle

Tags: c++, maven, opencv, gradle

I am creating a project that uses opencv C++ code. As of this moment I am only able to find the java executables being hosted in maven central at :-

```
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nu.pattern/opencv/2.4.9-4
```

So I installed opencv on my system and started using that for my project. In order to compile my project with the opencv headers I introduced the following in my build.gradle script:-

```
// C++ specific build configurations

// Acquiring environment variables
def opencvhome = System.getenv("OPENCV_HOME")

def opencvinclude = opencvhome + "\\include"

model {
    components {
        main(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            sources {
                cpp {
                    source {
                        srcDirs "src/main/cpp"
                        include "**/*.cpp"
                    }
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDirs "src/main/include", opencvinclude
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This was for including the necessary headers. Notice the opencvinclude part as picked up as an environment variable which I set to the install location before running the gradle build.

Now my question is how do I add additional linkage dependencies of opencv?

```
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html
```

I consulted the above documentation. It only covers dependencies that are themselves gradle projects. But opencv C++ is not a gradle project. Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the excerpt from build.gradle that configure static linkage with opencv libraries

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.example.oleg.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "fastcvUtils"

        //abiFilters += ["armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"]
        abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"

        // Link with static OpenCV libraries: the order is important!
        // The following order taken from OpenCV.mk
        def opencv_modules = ["shape", "stitching", "objdetect", "superres", "videostab", "calib3d", "features2d", "highgui", "videoio", "imgcodecs", "video", "photo", "ml", "imgproc", "flann", "core", "hal"]

        ldLibs += ["log","stdc++","dl", "z"]

        abiFilters.each { targetAbi ->
            println targetAbi

            opencv_modules.each{ module ->
                ldLibs += file(projectDir).absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/" + targetAbi + "/libopencv_" + module + ".a"
            }
        }

        cppFlags   += "-Werror"
        cppFlags   += "--debug"
        cppFlags   += "-frtti"
        cppFlags   += "-fexceptions"
        cppFlags += "-I/Users/Oleg/Downloads/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include"


        ldLibs += file(projectDir).absolutePath+"/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a"

        stl = "gnustl_static"

    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-android.pro')
            isJniDebuggable = true
            isDebuggable = true
        }

        debug {
            isJniDebuggable = true
            isDebuggable = true
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {

        create("arm") {
            ndk.with {

                abiFilters += "armeabi"
                println "*** building for arm"
            }

        }

        create("armv7") {
            ndk.with {

                abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
                println "*** building for armv7"
            }

        }

        create("x86") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "x86"
                println "*** building for x86"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It assumes that .a libraries were copied fron OpenCV SDK into jniLibs folder